# Microsoft Recommended Program Directories

Tags: .net, installation

Where can I find a listing of what Microsoft recommends for program install directories, application data, etc? (e.g. Best Practices)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1507923/does-microsoft-have-a-best-practices-document-regarding-the-storage-of-app-data-v

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum.

Comment: That shows how to get the directories, and reading it gives some good clues as to what should go where.  But is there a "Best Practices" document somewhere that gives more explicit information?

Comment: @Jim: Thanks @Forgotten: Have any other links?

Comment: The description of the special folders says a lot. Add this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx and you have the whole picture. Still, you have to know about roaming and non-roaming user when working with (local)ApplicationData and so on, but thats another gem. :)

Answer (score 1):

The comprehensive document on the subject is the "Windows User Experience", which used to be published as a book, but can now be found online in many places (such as http://www.scribd.com/doc/36857902/Windows-User-Experience)

Comment: I also found this: Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa511258.aspx.  I haven't yet found anything about the directories, though.

Answer (score 1):

Windows File System Namespace Usage Guidelines: [http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=88AD7E7C-4068-48B8-9503-E160A6693BBA&displaylang=en](https://web.archive.org/web/20120513044908/http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=88AD7E7C-4068-48B8-9503-E160A6693BBA&displaylang=en)

Download the PDF.

Most of the document is specific to Windows Vista.  The last section, titled "Accessing Well Known Folder Locations," discusses the `SHGetFolderPath` (Windows XP and earlier) and `SHGetKnownFolderPath` (Windows Vista) functions, which are what the .NET `Environment.GetFolderPath` method relies upon.

The `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration has been greatly expanded in .NET 4.0.  It includes a lot more values than the 3.5 version did.