# Obtain Current Users %APPDATA% Path and not Admins

Tags: windows, installation, nsis

I am looking to get the path to the current users `%APPDATA%` folder.

**Note:** I am aware of the variable `$APPDATA` BUT if you run your installer with `RequestExecutionLevel  admin` then `$APPDATA` will point to the admins roaming folder and NOT the current user's app data folder.

I need to find out the current users %APPDATA% path so I can write files to their roaming directory. Does anyone know how I can find this out?

```
RequestExecutionLevel  admin

Section "Main"
    MessageBox MB_OK "AppData is: $APPDATA" # knowtice that its the path to the admins folder not the current user's
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Hmm, no, an installer that acquired admin rights through the UAC prompt still runs with the non-elevated user's appdata folders.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for an installer that requires admin access to write to the current user's application data folder.  There are two cases: the first is that you're installing for all users, in which case the installer should not be responsible for writing to the application data folder, because then the application won't behave the same for other users.  Instead, write the data from the application itself on the first run.  The second case is that you're installing only for the current user, in which case you don't need admin privilege.

Comment: @HansPassant have you run my example code? For me it shows the admins %APPDATA% path. If it doesn't for you can explain how you did it? Is your user an admin or regular user

Comment: @HarryJohnston Whilst it doesn't make sense, Autodesk Revit does install both to ProgramData, Program Files, %APPDATA% and %LOCALAPPDATA%. I am installing an addin for Revit therefore I need to install to ProgramData, Program Files, %APPDATA%.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm fairly sure that Hans is right in saying that Windows Installer will normally present you with the non-elevated user's folders, but perhaps NSIS implements this differently.  One thought: many MSI installers come wrapped in an EXE file, and in this case it won't work unless the EXE has a manifest explicitly asking to be run without elevation.  Perhaps this is your scenario?

Comment: NSIS gets all shell constants (except ProgramFiles) from SHGetSpecialFolderPath meaning they come from somewhere in HKCU basically. MSI has a Windows service and often spawns several processes so the paths it gives you probably depends on several factors including .exe vs .msi files.

Answer (score 3):

The term "Current User" is ambiguous, do you mean:

- The user you get from `WTSQueryUserToken()`? (WinLogon)
- The user that the shell's taskbar is running as? (`GetShellWindow()`)
- The user (parent process) that started your setup process?

All of those can be different users if you are having fun with runas!

The comment from [Harry Johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467566/obtain-current-users-appdata-path-and-not-admins#comment34176839_22467566) is spot on and once you start mixing %ProgramFiles% and %AppData% and/or HKLM and HKCU your setup is broken in multi-user scenarios. What happens when a different user starts the application? They are not going to have your files in their %AppData%.

If the addin is installed/registered in a global location you can install the AppData "template" files in %ProgramFiles%, %CommonProgramFiles% or %ALLUSERSPROFILE% and when your addin runs as a specific user for the first time you copy the files to %AppData%.

[Active Setup](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aruns_blog/archive/2011/11/02/10176957.aspx) could be used as a alternative but it will probably require a log-off/log-on cycle.

If you cannot implement the delayed copy/install for some reason you are left with hacks like the [UAC plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/UAC_plug-in) which gives you some access to the user that started your installer...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for the advice but I found a [nice plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NT_Profile_Paths) that tells me the location of all User directories. I still cant figure out which user is currently logged in but I can figure out all non-admin users which is very useful.

```
!include "NTProfiles.nsi"

!macro HandleUserProfiles
    !define NTProfilePaths::IgnoreLocal

    !ifndef __UNINSTALL__
        ${EnumProfilePaths} HandleUserProfile
    !else
        ${EnumProfilePaths} un.HandleUserProfile
    !endif
!macroend

!macro HandleUserProfile prefix
Function ${prefix}HandleUserProfile

    Pop $R9

    !ifndef __UNINSTALL__
        # Copy files to user dir
        SetOutPath "$R9\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2013"  # $APPDATA = C:\ProgramData
        FILE /r "${INSTALLFILEDIR}\Addins\Revit_2013\myAddin.addin"
    !else
        Delete "$R9\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2013\myAddin.addin"
    !endif

    # Continue Enumeration
    Continue:
        Push ""
        Return
    # Stop Enumeration
    Stop:
        Push "~" # Any value other than an empty string will abort the enumeration
FunctionEnd
!macroend
!insertmacro HandleUserProfile ""
!insertmacro HandleUserProfile "un."
```