# Inno setup makes sqlite3 database read-only

Tags: python, sqlite, inno-setup

I'm making an installation package which is to be used on windows and includes a sqlite3 database (which is not read-only).

When then package has been installed the sqlite3 database has become read-only for some reason. By the way, I'm using python 2.7.3 (with sqlite3 lib) to read/write from it.

My question is, is there away for me to unlock the sqlite database to become read/write through a python script, bat script, or the inno setup script perhaps?

Or is there a way for me to modify my inno setup script to keep the sqlite database from becoming read-only in the first place?

I've tried searching the forums and googling for an answer but haven't succeeded in finding one.

THanks in advance!

Comment: Do you install it under Program Files? That's read-only for normal users, and data files should go elsewhere.

Comment: Yes. Oh, I see. I'll try to install it elsewhere then, thanks!

Comment: Please accept the answer so as to improve your credibility here. Otherwise, nobody is going to help you any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, anything inside the Program Files folder is meant to be read-only during normal use. Data files should be installed elsewhere. See here for more advice on where to put them:

[Does Microsoft have a best practices document regarding the storage of App Data vs User Data on different Windows Platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1507923/222914)